# leaflet - tile loading - error event

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet which displays offline tiles that have been created using maperitive. Everything works just fine but does anyone know how to trigger the error event in case the requested tile does not exist? In case the requested tile cannot be loaded, you can specify a default tile.

```
var myLayer = new L.TileLayer(..., {errorTileUrl: '/path/to/default/tile.png'});
```

which actually sets the default tile if there is an error loading the requested tile. But this is not exactly what I need. I need it to fire an event.

The leaflet code itself is pretty simple.

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/MapID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
myLayer.on('tileerror', function(error, tile) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(tile);
});
```

Ref: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.7.3/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L581

Does it help ?

Comment: Works for me and is included in Leaflet 0.73. Interestingly, the event doesn't bubble all the way up to the map, so you have to bind the listener to the layer (as this answer suggests). Also, the event is not documented on http://leafletjs.com/reference.html

Comment: Looks like the `tileerror` event was added [Nov 27, 2013](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/commit/82e43019eecd554d0491747a2ff63a481dfae058#diff-f1e6be67599c594731fff6191c710420R419)