# LeafletJS offline support

Tags: leaflet, maps, offline, react-leaflet

Am using leafletJS for showing offline maps using openstreet tiles and its working fine. We need to use atlast tool to generate tiles and able to do that. But how to handle case that if generated tiles are not matching with latitude and longitude which are coming from services then in leaflet is showing markers but background map tiles are not loading (I know it wont match so its not showing :) ) but is there any way / approach which I can figure out that latitude and longitude provided are not in range or in sync of map tiles generated for offline so that I can show meaningful message to end users and accordingly user / admin will take actions?

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine three approaches to this:

1. If you know which tiles you are generating (often times you are generating tiles in a bounding-box) you could hardcode that bounding-box and check if the given coordinate is inside or outside before adding the marker or jumping to the coordinate.
2. This question ([leaflet - tile loading - error event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342683/leaflet-tile-loading-error-event)) details a way to detect when Leaflet can't load a tile (for whatever reason: tile does not exist, no connection, ...). Maybe you could inform the user using that `tileerror` event.
3. You could convert the coordinate into its Slippy-Tilename equivalent and try to manually request that tile from your server / storage (for example using the Fetch-API). The conversion process is detailed (with code!) on the Openstreetmap-Wiki (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#ECMAScript_.28JavaScript.2FActionScript.2C_etc..29)